# Linear transformations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

[image]

Can anyone help guide me in answering this question? I am confused on if it is asking to find the eigenvectors and if so, how to set up the matrix?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Ker(T)=\{y\in C^{\infty}\, : \frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}-2\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0\}$.

(Ker(T) is just another notation for nullspace/nullity of a linear transformation. They mean the same)

Solving this equation using operator method . We see that $1$ is a double root of the auxiliary equation.

Hence the general solution of the differential equation is $(C_{1}+C_{2}x)e^{x}=C_{1}e^{x}+C_{2}xe^{x}$.

So the set $S=\{e^{x},xe^{x}\}$ is a set with only two functions and $span(S)=ker(T)$. This is true as $span(S)$ is just the solution space of the differential equation.

Also you can show that these two functions form a basis for $ker(T)$ as the functions are linearly independent as their [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) is non-zero.

PS:- If you do not know how to solve differential equations using operator method consisting of auxiliary equations,complementary functions and Particular integrals then I highly recommend learning it right now by means of a book or youtube videos or anything you like. It is a really handy and powerful tool.